# Create a list by looping throug array list of type with that Java variable

Tags: java, arraylist

I have array list of type `Warehouse`. Each Warehouse has a stock amount. The method `getStock()` returns the stock level.

I have an `ArrayList` of `Warehouse`. I want to get the stock of each warehouse in the list and add it to a list.

My code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Warehouses {

ArrayList<Warehouse> warehouses = new ArrayList<Warehouse>();

public Warehouses() {



    warehouses.add(new Warehouse("W1", 20, "RM13 8BB"));
    warehouses.add(new Warehouse("W2", 28, "RM13 8BB"));
    warehouses.add(new Warehouse("W3", 17, "RM13 8BB"));
}

public void stockList() {



    ArrayList<Integer> stockList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(Warehouse warehouse : warehouses) {

        Integer stock = warehouse.getStock();

        System.out.println(stock);

    }


}
}


class Warehouse
{
// instance variables - replace the example below with your own
private String warehouseID;
private int warehouseStock;
private String location;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Warehouse
 */
public Warehouse(String warehouseID, int warehouseStock, String location)
{
    // initialise instance variables
    warehouseID = warehouseID;
    warehouseStock = warehouseStock;
    location = location;
}

public int getStock(){
    return warehouseStock;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}
}
```

When I call `stockList()` I just get three empty values. What is wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think values are empty?

Answer (score 3):

Assign the constructor arguments of `Warehouse` to the class member variables rather than re-assigning the local variables themselves

```
public Warehouse(String warehouseID, int warehouseStock, String location) {
    this.warehouseID = warehouseID;
    this.warehouseStock = warehouseStock;
    this.location = location;
}
```